# Symfony2 batch action for list

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am looking on how to create batch action using checkbox for a list of data that I have stored in my db. Something like this was created through the admin generator with the Jobeet tutorial for Symfony1.4 when you could extend the life of a list of jobs:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/12?orm=Doctrine

Anyone has informations or know where I could find information about how to tie checkboxes (one by line) to a list of data and create a form with the lot so that I can batch update the entire list?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just to answer myself in case someone look to solve a similar problem: I was looking to use forms from the framework because I wanted to have crsf protection on it. But thinking about it, there is no need for crsf protection here. So all there is to do is manually create a form in the twig template with checkboxes for each line and add an action in the controller that will batch update the data. Nice and easy!

Comment: You need CSRF protection on forms that alter data